# Headphones work only when unplugged and plugged in again

Tags: 18.04, sound, dell, headphones

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu 18.04.

When I plug in my headphones I can listen to audio. Everything works fine.
Except from the shrill noise I get when I don't play any audio.

Another issue is that, if I leave the headphones plugged in and reboot the laptop, it appears that the headphones don't work, i.e. I cannot listen to any audio.
To be able to hear anything I have to unplug and plug in the headphones again.

How to fix these issues?

---

UPDATE

When I run `journalctl --follow` and plug in the headphones I get:

```
Oct 14 18:31:24 xps systemd[1444]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Oct 14 18:31:25 xps dbus-daemon[1718]: [session uid=1000 pid=1718] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Oct 14 18:31:25 xps systemd[1444]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Oct 14 18:31:55 xps wpa_supplicant[914]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-74 noise=-101 txrate=6000
Oct 14 18:31:57 xps wpa_supplicant[914]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-82 noise=-101 txrate=6000
```

I then leave the headphones in and reboot.
After I run `journalctl -b` I get:

```
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: Linux version 4.15.0-36-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-36.39-generic 4.15.18)
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic root=UUID=c02749bd-9e22-473e-8668-62d1fc153ee0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x000000000009efff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000650ddfff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000650de000-0x00000000650defff] ACPI NVS
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000650df000-0x00000000650dffff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000650e0000-0x000000006c606fff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006c607000-0x000000006f408fff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006f409000-0x000000006f485fff] ACPI data
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006f486000-0x000000006f5b4fff] ACPI NVS
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006f5b5000-0x000000006ff34fff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006ff35000-0x000000006fffefff] type 20
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000006ffff000-0x000000006fffffff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000070000000-0x0000000077ffffff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078000000-0x0000000078dfffff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078e00000-0x000000007f7fffff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000087c7fffff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: efi: EFI v2.70 by American Megatrends
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x6f422000  ACPI=0x6f422000  SMBIOS=0xf0000  SMBIOS 3.0=0xf0020  ESRT=0x6fc4a118  MEMATTR=0x6a414018 
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: secureboot: Secure boot could not be determined (mode 0)
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: DMI: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9570/07GHH0, BIOS 1.5.0 09/03/2018
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: e820: last_pfn = 0x87c800 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: MTRR default type: write-back
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   00000-9FFFF write-back
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   C0000-FFFFF write-protect
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel: MTRR variable ranges enabled:
Oct 13 14:46:31 xps kernel:   0 base 0080000000 mask 7F80000000 uncachable
```

The output from `suo lsof ...` is:

```
    Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID             USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd      1             root    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd      1             root    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd      1             root    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd      1             root    3w   CHR   1,11      0t0   12 /dev/kmsg
systemd      1             root   23u   CHR  13,67      0t0  152 /dev/input/event3
systemd      1             root   25r   CHR 10,235      0t0  393 /dev/autofs
systemd      1             root  107u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
systemd      1             root  109u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
systemd      1             root  110u   CHR  13,69      0t0  288 /dev/input/event5
systemd      1             root  111u   CHR  13,70      0t0  290 /dev/input/event6
systemd      1             root  112u   CHR  13,65      0t0  150 /dev/input/event1
systemd      1             root  113u   CHR  13,66      0t0  151 /dev/input/event2
systemd      1             root  114u   CHR  13,78      0t0  513 /dev/input/event14
systemd      1             root  115u   CHR  13,75      0t0  466 /dev/input/event11
systemd      1             root  116u   CHR  13,76      0t0  468 /dev/input/event12
systemd      1             root  117u   CHR  13,77      0t0  477 /dev/input/event13
systemd      1             root  118u   CHR  13,73      0t0  437 /dev/input/event9
systemd      1             root  119u   CHR  13,72      0t0  436 /dev/input/event8
systemd      1             root  120u   CHR  13,74      0t0  458 /dev/input/event10
systemd      1             root  121u   CHR  13,68      0t0  155 /dev/input/event4
systemd      1             root  122u   CHR  13,71      0t0  432 /dev/input/event7
kdevtmpfs   79             root  cwd    DIR    0,6     4460    2 /dev
kdevtmpfs   79             root  rtd    DIR    0,6     4460    2 /dev
systemd-j  321             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-j  321             root    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-j  321             root    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-j  321             root    7w   CHR   1,11      0t0   12 /dev/kmsg
systemd-j  321             root    9u   CHR   1,11      0t0   12 /dev/kmsg
systemd-u  341             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-r  624  systemd-resolve    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-t  625 systemd-timesync    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
cupsd      878             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
rsyslogd   879           syslog    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
rsyslogd   879           syslog    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
rsyslogd   879           syslog    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
rsyslogd   879           syslog    4r   CHR    1,9      0t0   11 /dev/urandom
thermald   882             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
dbus-daem  884       messagebus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
NetworkMa  910             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
accounts-  911             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
avahi-dae  913            avahi    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
wpa_suppl  914             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
wpa_suppl  914             root   11r   CHR  10,62      0t0    4 /dev/rfkill
wpa_suppl  914             root   17r   CHR  10,62      0t0    4 /dev/rfkill
acpid      918             root    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
acpid      918             root    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
acpid      918             root    4r   CHR  13,64      0t0  149 /dev/input/event0
acpid      918             root    5r   CHR  13,65      0t0  150 /dev/input/event1
acpid      918             root    6r   CHR  13,74      0t0  458 /dev/input/event10
acpid      918             root    7r   CHR  13,79      0t0  538 /dev/input/event15
acpid      918             root    8r   CHR  13,80      0t0  539 /dev/input/event16
acpid      918             root    9r   CHR  13,81      0t0  540 /dev/input/event17
acpid      918             root   10r   CHR  13,82      0t0  541 /dev/input/event18
acpid      918             root   11r   CHR  13,83      0t0  543 /dev/input/event19
acpid      918             root   12r   CHR  13,66      0t0  151 /dev/input/event2
acpid      918             root   13r   CHR  13,84      0t0  544 /dev/input/event20
acpid      918             root   14r   CHR  13,67      0t0  152 /dev/input/event3
acpid      918             root   15r   CHR  13,68      0t0  155 /dev/input/event4
acpid      918             root   16r   CHR  13,69      0t0  288 /dev/input/event5
acpid      918             root   17r   CHR  13,70      0t0  290 /dev/input/event6
acpid      918             root   18r   CHR  13,72      0t0  436 /dev/input/event8
acpid      918             root   19r   CHR  13,73      0t0  437 /dev/input/event9
ModemMana  919             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ModemMana  919             root    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
cron       920             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
networkd-  921             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
udisksd    922             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
avahi-dae  923            avahi    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-l  925             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd-l  925             root   14u   CHR  13,67      0t0  152 /dev/input/event3
systemd-l  925             root   15u   CHR  13,65      0t0  150 /dev/input/event1
systemd-l  925             root   16u   CHR  13,64      0t0  149 /dev/input/event0
systemd-l  925             root   17u   CHR  13,66      0t0  151 /dev/input/event2
systemd-l  925             root   18u   CHR  13,73      0t0  437 /dev/input/event9
systemd-l  925             root   19u   CHR  13,72      0t0  436 /dev/input/event8
systemd-l  925             root   20u   CHR  13,68      0t0  155 /dev/input/event4
systemd-l  925             root   21u   CHR    4,6      0t0   25 /dev/tty6
systemd-l  925             root   24u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
systemd-l  925             root   26u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
systemd-l  925             root   27u   CHR    4,2      0t0   21 /dev/tty2
systemd-l  925             root   28u   CHR  13,67      0t0  152 /dev/input/event3
systemd-l  925             root   29u   CHR  13,69      0t0  288 /dev/input/event5
systemd-l  925             root   30u   CHR  13,70      0t0  290 /dev/input/event6
systemd-l  925             root   31u   CHR  13,65      0t0  150 /dev/input/event1
systemd-l  925             root   32u   CHR  13,66      0t0  151 /dev/input/event2
systemd-l  925             root   33u   CHR  13,78      0t0  513 /dev/input/event14
systemd-l  925             root   34u   CHR  13,75      0t0  466 /dev/input/event11
systemd-l  925             root   35u   CHR  13,76      0t0  468 /dev/input/event12
systemd-l  925             root   36u   CHR  13,77      0t0  477 /dev/input/event13
systemd-l  925             root   37u   CHR  13,73      0t0  437 /dev/input/event9
systemd-l  925             root   38u   CHR  13,72      0t0  436 /dev/input/event8
systemd-l  925             root   39u   CHR  13,74      0t0  458 /dev/input/event10
systemd-l  925             root   40u   CHR  13,68      0t0  155 /dev/input/event4
systemd-l  925             root   41u   CHR  13,71      0t0  432 /dev/input/event7
systemd-l  925             root   54u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
irqbalanc  927             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
bluetooth  931             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
bluetooth  931             root   12u   CHR  10,62      0t0    4 /dev/rfkill
snapd      935             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
polkitd    972             root    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
polkitd    972             root    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
polkitd    972             root    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
colord     978           colord    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
cups-brow  982             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gdm3      1064             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gdm-sessi 1084             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd   1108              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
(sd-pam   1109              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gdm-wayla 1120              gdm    0u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
dbus-daem 1122              gdm    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-ses 1124              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-she 1130              gdm  mem    CHR  226,0           223 /dev/dri/card0
gnome-she 1130              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-she 1130              gdm   11u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gnome-she 1130              gdm   12u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
upowerd   1143             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
upowerd   1143             root   11r   CHR  13,64      0t0  149 /dev/input/event0
Xwayland  1160              gdm  mem    CHR  226,0           223 /dev/dri/card0
Xwayland  1160              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
Xwayland  1160              gdm    9u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
Xwayland  1160              gdm   10u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
at-spi-bu 1177              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
dbus-daem 1182              gdm    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
at-spi2-r 1184              gdm    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
pulseaudi 1188              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
pulseaudi 1188              gdm   18u   CHR  116,2      0t0  525 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1188              gdm   25u   CHR  116,2      0t0  525 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1188              gdm   30u   CHR  116,2      0t0  525 /dev/snd/controlC0
rtkit-dae 1189            rtkit    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-daem 1212              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-dcon 1215              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-dcon 1215              gdm    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-dcon 1215              gdm    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1218              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1218              gdm    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1218              gdm    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1218              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
ibus-port 1220              gdm    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
boltd     1232             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
packageki 1233             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-xsett 1234              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-xsett 1234              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gsd-a11y- 1239              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-clipb 1240              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-clipb 1240              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gsd-color 1241              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-color 1241              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gsd-datet 1245              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-house 1246              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-keybo 1247              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-keybo 1247              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gsd-media 1251              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-media 1251              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gsd-mouse 1252              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-power 1253              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-power 1253              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gsd-print 1254              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-rfkil 1257              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-scree 1260              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-shari 1261              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-smart 1272              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-sound 1274              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-wacom 1275              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-wacom 1275              gdm    4u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
dconf-ser 1288              gdm    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-engi 1293              gdm    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-engi 1293              gdm    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-engi 1293              gdm    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gdm-sessi 1340             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
canonical 1405             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
whoopsie  1408         whoopsie    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
kerneloop 1412         kernoops    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
kerneloop 1412         kernoops    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
kerneloop 1412         kernoops    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
kerneloop 1426         kernoops    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
kerneloop 1426         kernoops    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
kerneloop 1426         kernoops    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
teamviewe 1437             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
teamviewe 1437             root    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
teamviewe 1437             root    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
systemd   1444            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
(sd-pam   1445            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-key 1528            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-key 1528            ursus    1r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-key 1528            ursus    2r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-key 1528            ursus    3r   CHR    1,9      0t0   11 /dev/urandom
gdm-x-ses 1672            ursus    0u   CHR    4,2      0t0   21 /dev/tty2
Xorg      1674            ursus  mem    CHR  226,0           223 /dev/dri/card0
Xorg      1674            ursus    0u   CHR    4,2      0t0   21 /dev/tty2
Xorg      1674            ursus   11u   CHR    4,2      0t0   21 /dev/tty2
Xorg      1674            ursus   12u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
Xorg      1674            ursus   13u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
Xorg      1674            ursus   21u   CHR  13,67      0t0  152 /dev/input/event3
Xorg      1674            ursus   24u   CHR  13,69      0t0  288 /dev/input/event5
Xorg      1674            ursus   25u   CHR  13,70      0t0  290 /dev/input/event6
Xorg      1674            ursus   26u   CHR  13,65      0t0  150 /dev/input/event1
Xorg      1674            ursus   27u   CHR  13,66      0t0  151 /dev/input/event2
Xorg      1674            ursus   28u   CHR  13,78      0t0  513 /dev/input/event14
Xorg      1674            ursus   29u   CHR  13,75      0t0  466 /dev/input/event11
Xorg      1674            ursus   30u   CHR  13,76      0t0  468 /dev/input/event12
Xorg      1674            ursus   31u   CHR  13,77      0t0  477 /dev/input/event13
Xorg      1674            ursus   32u   CHR  13,73      0t0  437 /dev/input/event9
Xorg      1674            ursus   33u   CHR  13,72      0t0  436 /dev/input/event8
Xorg      1674            ursus   34u   CHR  13,74      0t0  458 /dev/input/event10
Xorg      1674            ursus   35u   CHR  13,68      0t0  155 /dev/input/event4
Xorg      1674            ursus   36u   CHR  13,71      0t0  432 /dev/input/event7
dbus-daem 1718            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-ses 1726            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ssh-agent 1809            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ssh-agent 1809            ursus    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ssh-agent 1809            ursus    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
at-spi-bu 1812            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
dbus-daem 1817            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
at-spi2-r 1819            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-she 1836            ursus  mem    CHR  226,0           223 /dev/dri/card0
gnome-she 1836            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-she 1836            ursus    9u   CHR  226,0      0t0  223 /dev/dri/card0
gvfsd     1842            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfsd-fus 1847            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfsd-fus 1847            ursus    3u   CHR 10,229      0t0   85 /dev/fuse
pulseaudi 1858            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
pulseaudi 1858            ursus    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
pulseaudi 1858            ursus    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
pulseaudi 1858            ursus   17u   CHR  116,2      0t0  525 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1858            ursus   24u   CHR  116,2      0t0  525 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1858            ursus   29u   CHR  116,2      0t0  525 /dev/snd/controlC0
ibus-daem 1882            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-dcon 1886            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-dcon 1886            ursus    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-dcon 1886            ursus    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1888            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1888            ursus    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-x11  1888            ursus    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-port 1890            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-she 1905            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
evolution 1920            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
goa-daemo 1928            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
goa-daemo 1928            ursus   13r   CHR    1,9      0t0   11 /dev/urandom
dconf-ser 1930            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfsd-met 1933            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
goa-ident 1949            ursus    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfs-udis 1953            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfs-mtp- 1958            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfs-goa- 1962            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfs-gpho 1966            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfs-afc- 1970            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-mouse 1975            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-power 1976            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-print 1978            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-rfkil 1980            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-rfkil 1980            ursus    7u   CHR  10,62      0t0    4 /dev/rfkill
gsd-rfkil 1980            ursus   10w   CHR  10,62      0t0    4 /dev/rfkill
gsd-scree 1982            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-shari 1983            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-smart 1987            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-sound 1992            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-xsett 1993            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-wacom 1998            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-a11y- 2009            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-color 2010            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-datet 2014            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-clipb 2016            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-keybo 2018            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-media 2019            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-house 2022            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gsd-print 2067            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-sof 2070            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-sof 2070            ursus   16r   CHR    1,9      0t0   11 /dev/urandom
gsd-disk- 2077            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
nautilus- 2079            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfsd-tra 2102            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
evolution 2117            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-engi 2124            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-engi 2124            ursus    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
ibus-engi 2124            ursus    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
evolution 2136            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
evolution 2147            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
evolution 2166            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
fwupd     2198             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
update-no 2913            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
deja-dup- 3027            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gvfsd-htt 4800            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
dhclient  8029             root    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
dhclient  8029             root    1w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
dhclient  8029             root    2w   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-ter 8220            ursus    0r   CHR    1,3      0t0    6 /dev/null
gnome-ter 8220            ursus   13u   CHR    5,2      0t0   88 /dev/ptmx
```

Comment: Watch the logs as you plug in the headphones, with `journalctl --follow`. See what your system did at boot, `journalctl -b

Comment: @waltinator I have updated the description of the issue. Can't tell if that reveals anything.

Comment: 1. Unplug. 2. `journalctl --follow`. 3. Plug. 4. Check for "shrill noise"? 5. `sudo lsof  +D /dev | tee devices.open.txt` .

Comment: @waltinator I hav eupdated the update. About the output from `journalctl --follow`: repeating the procedure may result in different signal, `signal=-79`, `signal=-86`

Comment: Try [Option # 3 here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501)

Answer (score 1):

I have identified the source of the shrill/hissing noise: it appears after running

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw powertop
sudo tlp start
```

Removed it. Solved this issue.

I still need to unplug and plug the headphones back in every time I restart the laptop though.