# How to troubleshoot lack of sound in only one of the bluetooth earphones?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 19.04

This kind of problems is probably as old as bluetooth headsets started becoming more popular... This time I can connect the headset, sound settings show both left and right as available and at full volume, but the sound only comes from the right earphone when A2DP is enabled. If I switch to HSP/HFP, sound comes from the left as expected.

UPD: I followed all the steps from [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs). The difference between my problem and his is that I don't get the test sounds at all and all the other programs just output into the right earphone, but not left. In alsamixer nothing is muted.

UPD2: Here's the result of `apt list --installed | grep -E "pulseaudio|pulseaudio-module-bluetooth|pavucontrol|bluez"`:

```
bluez-cups/disco,now 5.50-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
bluez-obexd/disco,now 5.50-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bluez/disco,now 5.50-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/disco,now 1.15.90-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
pavucontrol/disco,now 3.0-4 amd64 [installed]
pulseaudio-dlna/disco,disco,now 0.5.3+git20170406-1 all [installed]
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/disco,now 1:12.2-2ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
pulseaudio-utils/disco,now 1:12.2-2ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio/disco,now 1:12.2-2ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
```

Worth noting that this issue happened after an update this week, here's the list of packages that were updated:

```
cups-bsd:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups-client:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups-common:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups-core-drivers:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups-daemon:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups-ipp-utils:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1))
cups-ppdc:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups-server-common:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
cups:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
libblockdev-crypto2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev-fs2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev-loop2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev-part-err2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev-part2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev-swap2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev-utils2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libblockdev2:amd64 (2.20-7, 2.20-7ubuntu0.1)
libcups2:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.2.10-4ubuntu2, 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1)
libegl-mesa0:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libegl1-mesa:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libgbm1:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libgif7:amd64 (5.1.4-3, 5.1.4-3ubuntu0.1)
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libglapi-mesa:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libglapi-mesa:i386 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libglx-mesa0:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libglx-mesa0:i386 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
libprocps7:amd64 (2:3.3.15-2ubuntu2, 2:3.3.15-2ubuntu2.1)
libxatracker2:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1, 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1)
procps:amd64 (2:3.3.15-2ubuntu2, 2:3.3.15-2ubuntu2.1)
```

It doesn't look like there's anything bluetooth related, but maybe you'd know more.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs

Comment: Thanks for that. The difference between my issue and his is that system sound tests don't output from the left earphone. And after trying option 2 I can't connect my headset at all...

Comment: You need to reboot after trying option # 2. A reboot is a must to rebuild correct new configuration files. Please let me know if you need help

Comment: The reboot is part of the instructions... Of course I did it

Comment: Please continue trying option # 3 and if not fixed try option # 4 . And if not fixed after that. Please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Please run ( apt list --installed | grep -E "pulseaudio|pulseaudio-module-bluetooth|pavucontrol|bluez" ) and [edit] your question adding the output. This is to make sure required packages are installed. Thank you

Comment: Please also check for updates for these packages by running `apt-cache policy pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pavucontrol bluez` . If updated versions are available please run `sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pavucontrol bluez` then reboot your system.

Comment: Are you sure no other packages were updated? Did you try option #3 in the answer I linked above. It will fix conflicts between old configuration and the updated packages if any

Comment: I can assure you I've followed the instructions precisely multiple times. I extracted this list of packages from the logs, so I'm as sure as the logs are complete

Comment: I guess then. It is worth trying to reinstall the related packages `sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils pulseaudio-dlna pavucontrol bluez` then reboot your system and try

Comment: That didn't do it. I really don't think reinstalling packages is the solution anymore unfortunately...

Comment: I am out of solutions. I apologize I couldn't help. This information will however help whoever comes to help after me. Have a nice day.