# Surround sound problems with Ubuntu Studio 19.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I upgraded one of my desktop PCs from Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3 to 19.04.

The most important reason to do that was to try to solve some audio problems.

I don't "catch" some improvement around that audio issues.

Even worst, now I cannot to get more than two stereo channels from the audio card!

When I use:

```
speaker-test -l 1 -c 8 -t sine -f 440
```

(Terminal session command line), I just get the standard Left-Front and Right-Front audio channels to sound. The other (surround) channels appears as: "Unused".

I checked the "/etc/pulse/daemon.conf" file and all is fine.

I don't have performed any change into any configuration file!

So... What's wrong here?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please try options 1 - 4 in this answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501 and see if it helps. It is not unusual to have conflicting audio configurations after upgrades.

Comment: I tried all your ideas and... Nothing! I guess I will have to wait to the next 19.10 upgrade and to perform a "from-the-scratch" installation. That's my life!