# Displayport to HDMI no audio have video

Tags: hdmi, displayport

Lenovo M58 Thinkcentre

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-54-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 2 × Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 3.3 GiB of RAM

Displayport to Input 5 HDMI 5
HDMI 5 of a Sharp TV

Have video but no audio
Settings display Sharp HDMI (HDMI-1) 1360 X 768
Sharp TV LS-52D85U

No HDMI option on audio

Tried suggestions at these links with no luck

- https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/
- https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1404/
- [HDMI sound not working after upgrading to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230002/hdmi-sound-not-working-after-upgrading-to-20-04)

  `aplay -l`

List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices

```
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1882 Analog [AD1882 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1882 Alt Analog [AD1882 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, the displayport that I had was capable of audio with other systems.

Comment: It should of worked.  After extensive review, I am not the only one with the issue.  And many seem to point to Ubuntu as at fault.  That said I have not time for that, scripts, etc especially years in Windows where it just work.  The solution was adding speakers.  Perhaps the TV in question was part of the problem.  Currently enjoying cutting the cord, watching sports and trying out Steam.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your DisplayPort adapter doesn't support sound.  Replace it with hardware that does support audio.  A quick search on Amazon should find one.  Just make sure it has audio support