# Output Device on GNOME settings shows Speakers and Headphone separately

Tags: sound, headphones, 20.04

[image]
Hello All,

On 18.04.4, there was only one output device. And when I inserted a headset, the sound was playing on headset automatically.

On 20.04 I am having to select output device as headphone when connecting earphone or headset.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

Open the alsa configuration file: 
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Add the following line to the end of this file:
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

Save and close the file and reboot your system.

Source: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% what you mean.but it sounds as if your headset is not the default device....besides. ..are you using a usb-headset or just plug into the Jack of the laptop?

....you could try installing pavucontrol and take a look at your devices:

sudo apt install pavucontrol

Comment: I mean when I am say watching a movie on laptop speakers, and I plug in a 3.5 earphone jack, the sound continues to play in the laptop speaker. On 18.04 it was auto-switching when I plugged my earphone.