# Sound does not work in headphones through 3.5 jack in a laptop Dell 5565, Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: laptop, headphones

Yesterday I installed Xubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Inspirion 5565 laptop. Everything works well except for the sound in the headphones. If you turn on the headphones after turning on the laptop, then there is sound in them; if you turn them off and reconnect, there is no sound. Sound comes from the speakers of the laptop. The laptop and headphones are working (the second system has Windows 10 installed - there the sound in the headphones works without problems, regardless of the number of disconnections and connections). Please help solve the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbN3i.png)

Comment: Seems like similar problem as me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230333/output-device-on-gnome-settings-shows-speakers-and-headphone-separately/1230695#1230695

Comment: have you tried all of the options available in system settings related to sound?  Different flavors handle this differently, but you should be able to change output devices - the built in speaker and headphone jack are usually different devices.

Comment: Nmath, I tried all the options available in the system settings. Nothing helps. In the system settings I tried to switch audio outputs, this does not help. I repeat, when I turn on the headphones for the first time after turning on the laptop, there is sound in them and the system settings automatically switch from speakers to headphones. Further, when disconnecting and reconnecting the headphones, there is no sound in them. Although the system settings indicate that the headphones are connected and working. Screenshot attached. The problem is clearly programmatic in nature.