# make switching between audio profiles permanent in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, output

First, preface. So after updating my system to ubuntu 20.04, the laptop speakers stopped working (output changed to dummy output), even though the sound was working fine when external speakers were connected. After going through a tonne of solutions and an infinite number of restarts, somehow I managed to listen again to some Simon and Garfunkel. (Thanks to the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230407/no-sound-on-arm-ubuntu-20-04/1231192#1231192))  :)

Now, the issue is every time I reboot my machine, I have to fire up *pavucontrol*, then switch to the profile there ("analog stereo duplex (unavailable)"), which is frankly, a bit inconvenient. Any solutions?

PS. Already tried and failed on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs/1165640#1165640) solution.