# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04 XFCE (ARM) VM

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, xfce

Running Ubuntu XFCE 20.04, the ARM version, does not have sound.
Playing music with volume on, keeps silent.
I must admit that it runs in a QEMU virtualization environment (UTM) on a Macbook Pro M1, so I thought is was the virtualization software, but a Windows 11 VM plays music flawlessly. I used wired headphones to test as I have no speakers or Bluetooth audio attached to the Macbook. These do work in native macOS and in a Windows 11 VM.
I found this webpage with a similar problem (on a real computer, no VM) and tried these options to no avail.
[No sound on arm ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230407/no-sound-on-arm-ubuntu-20-04)
`aplay -l` results in:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`alsa-info` returns:

```
ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
--------------------------------

This script visits the following commands/files to collect diagnostic
information about your ALSA installation and sound related hardware.

  dmesg
  lspci
  aplay
  amixer
  alsactl
  /proc/asound/
  /sys/class/sound/
  ~/.asoundrc (etc.)

See '/usr/sbin/alsa-info --help' for command line options.

Newer version detected: 0.5.1
To view the ChangeLog, please visit http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh.changelog
ALSA-Info script has been downloaded /tmp/alsa-info.e39uLe4Mvu.
Please, re-run it from new location.
```

I tried all options of `pavucontrol` but it remained silent.

Is there any way to get sound in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact problem on my VM Ubuntu. After long unsuccessful search I discovered next simple solution:

1. Play any audio or video in Ubuntu;
2. While playing open your main OS;
3. Change level of volume in usual manner;
4. Return to your Ubuntu.

Comment: Does not work. I tried on macOS Monterey with Ubuntu 22.04 VM under UTM/QEMU.