# Sound from computer speakers only (All normal sound output options show) - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04

In the SOUND settings menu, I have HDMI outputs for each monitor, and one wireless stereo headset option to select from.

The issue is:
I can select any of the output options, but when testing, only the built-in computer speakers play.

I just upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04, and immediately saw the issue.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501

Comment: Option #3 solved the issue! Pulse Audio must have had old configuration files during the upgrade. Thanks @Raffa