# microphone stopped working despite being detected

Tags: sound, microphone

External microphones on my device no longer seem to work, it is as if their gain is being continuously set to 0.

I know that this is not a microphone hardware issue because I tested on my Windows partition and the mics work fine. I also tried plugging in different mics on Ubuntu and they didn't work either. When I record myself with my computer's onboard internal mic, it is very noisy and barely intelligible, as if the recording levels were very low and gain is being blasted to bring it up to a "normal" level .

When I view settings in alsamixer I see:
[image]

Similarly, in my sound settings I can see that the microphone is successfully detected, yet no levels are present
[image]

When I record my voice in Audacity it is of course completely silent.

Audio output seems to be working fine however, I can play sound both through my onboard speakers and headphones.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: @Raffa this fixed the problem of the super noisy on-board mic recording, though didn't fix the problem of getting audio input from an external mic. It still detects a mic has been plugged in, but no audio

Comment: How did you decide that your microphone is detected? I only see a single Build In microphone in your screan shot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hitting F6 in alsamixer, which should show up a list of sound cards on your machine. Your mic could be one of those, and need the volume raising there too.

Likewise F4 from alsamixer for main input, which you may have done already, but is worth checking.

The mic on your second picture is the onboard mic not the usb one. Have you tried rebooting with the mic plugged in? My experience with external mics has always been nicer after doing that

If you see your mic in alsa soundcards, but your "input" alsa device is something funny instead of your mic, and it's still not showing on sound options, you might need to reorder your audio devices, which arch has a tutorial for [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture/Troubleshooting#Setting_the_default_microphone/capture_device)