# No Sound Output

Tags: sound, 20.04

I have an HP Pavilion (laptop) and the audio worked fine (both internal speakers and headset) with Ubuntu 19.10. After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 the internal speakers worked but the headset didn't. In the process of trying to fix the headset I broke it, no audio output. I was following the answer for [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs/1165640#1165640) and after option #2, no sound.

output of: aplay -l | grep card
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3241 Analog [ALC3241 Analog]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 1 [HDMI 2]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 1 [HDMI 3]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 1 [HDMI 4]

Any help figuring this out is appreciated. I'll be happy to provide any information needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but I have not really fixed the problem. I read somewhere that windows writes to registers to setup audio (and probably other stuff) but doesn't clear them on exit. I booted into windows 10 and played some audio, the internal speakers worked. I then plugged in the headset, it also worked. I booted back into Ubuntu 20.04 and the internal speakers and headset now work. It appears to me Ubuntu 20.04 is not setting registers for the audio to work.

I don't know who to report this bug to (my opinion) but it is late an I'm going to bed. I'll work on how to report this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had what appears to be the same issue (the one you had before attempting any fixes) and a version of Option #3 in that answer you linked was what worked for me.

Essentially, I performed the steps below.

1. Delete the old pulseaudio configuration (`rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/`).
2. Log out.
3. Log back in (which causes the configuration to be regenerated).
4. Configure your sound settings and confirm that it works as intended.

Also note that the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 made changes to the /etc/pulse/default.pa configuration file so make sure you apply those changes if you had previously modified it. I don't think that would be an issue in your case but I figured I should mention it. Below is the diff I got besides the changes I knew I had made myself.

```
-### Load additional modules from GConf settings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
+### Load additional modules from GSettings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.

-.ifexists module-gconf.so
+.ifexists module-gsettings.so
 .nofail
-load-module module-gconf
+load-module module-gsettings
 .fail
 .endif

-### Automatically move streams to the default sink if the sink they are
-### connected to dies, similar for sources
-load-module module-rescue-streams
```

Answer (score 0):

Has a similar issue. There was a patch released that fixed it.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/690180