# HDMI audio output option not detected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 20.04

Since I upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 the HDMI audio output option is not available. The option is not there in the sound settings GUI and in the pulseaudio volume control all profiles show as `(unplugged) (unavailable)`

I'm using NVidia GTX 1660 and have checked for driver updates and all.

I have tried multiple other answers which are more or less similar but in no case all the profiles shown in pavc were (unplugged)(unavailable) so I think it is specific to 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: @Raffa I have already tried all the steps in that answer. but no help. Not sure what the issue here is.

Comment: @Raffa that answer even disabled my bluetooth audio. So I guess it's more of an issue creator than an asnwer.

Comment: I apologize for that please run `sudo apt install alsa-base libcanberra-pulse pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal` .... This should restore your Bluetooth and reinstall removed packages. I also edited the answer to remove the part that might cause issues.

Comment: I reported the problem at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1890285.