# With audio or without? It's Ubuntu's choice

Tags: 20.04, sound

I wonder if someone could help me, because as the title says, Ubuntu doesn't really likes to play sound...
I turn on my laptop and sometimes it plays sound, sometimes not and sometimes it plays and some minutes later, it doesn't plays anymore, what is kind of annoying. Do you know what can I do (beside don't listen to music or videos)??? I already tried restarting the PC (rarely works), restart ALSA with `sudo alsa force-reload`, I checked the `alsamixer` command to check the mixer and everything there is OK, I've checked the output and it detects the speakers... On Windows the sound works perfectly, so the speaker is perfect. Can anyone help me?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x64 and my audio device is Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: Even I had this problem found this and the step 1 worked for me: removing and reinstalling, I think this kills the dependency of the other apps or some loop it gets into so reinstalling is my first instinct. Let me know if you've already tried. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Hi, I already tried that lots of times, as I said up there. It doesn't works (I mean, now it's working perfectly, but sometimes it doesn't)

Comment: @Raffa I haven't tried the 3rd option. I will try when it doesn't work again.

Comment: @Raffa, I already tried the 3rd step and I don't think it worked, because when I tried to do that step, the terminal said there was no such file or directory. Then, I executed `sudo apt purge --remove pulseaudio` and during the purge it said that there was no such file or directory again. Then, I installed it again and rebooted my PC and it's fine. Resuming, I don't really know if that was going to work, because I haven't found any directory with that name...

Comment: You only need to run the first command: `mv  ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse_old/` then reboot. The rest of commands under option #3 is for restoring the old configuration directory which you have renamed in the first command. You probably ran all the commands which is not how it works. If purging then reinstalling **pulseaudio** solved the problem, then running `mv  ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse_old/` then rebooting should solve it as well, because, `sudo apt remove pulseaudio` does not remove **`~/.config/pulse/`** while `sudo apt purge --remove pulseaudio` does. That is why.