# Sound stopped working after crash Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I had an unexpected system crash and when I came back, the sound wouldn't work on wired headphones or the built in speakers. (This is an Alienware 15r1.) The indicators in Settings->Sound show movement when I play audio files. I've tried both HDMI sound and the PCH sound, no luck. Here's what I've tried:

- `alsactl restore` (as well as doing this with `sudo`)
- purging and reinstalling `alsa-base` `pulseaudio` `alsa-utils` `pulseaudio-utils` `pavucontrol`
- messing around in `alsamixer`
- `alsa force-reload`
- blowing up `~/.config/pulse`
- checking for missing drivers, kernel modules, etc
- the procedure here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

The only weird thing I can see is this output from `alsactl`:

```
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
alsa-lib main.c:1021:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:0 (empty configuration)
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Intel Haswell HDMI" "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000" "0x1028" "0x0685"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
alsa-lib main.c:1021:(snd_use_case_mgr_open) error: failed to import hw:1 (empty configuration)
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Creative CA0132" "HDA:11020011,10280685,00100918" "0x1028" "0x0685"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

Here's my alsa-info output: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=38c54b284f92305405593c1a6240699fbc94d455

Let me know if there's any other output you think is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

`/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` appears to be corrupted, empty or has permissions issues.

To fix this, run in the terminal:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/alsa/asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state.old
```

then, run:

```
sudo alsactl --file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state store
```

then, run:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

then, run:

```
mv  ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse_old/
```

then, run:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

or just reboot your system.

If that didn't work, check the `alsamixer` settings as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501) then repeat the above steps.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but sadly this didn't work. I may end up reinstalling ubuntu, as it seems sound works if i boot from a live CD

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, after trying some more things I found here and elsewhere I ended up reinstalling from a Live CD.

Comment: I have too many critical things on my system to reinstall. This is ridiculous. I'm not doing that. I need sound for phone calls, and I currently have nothing.

Comment: Try a USB or Bluetooth headset