# I can no longer change the volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

So I started my computer and realized that I can no longer Fn+F2 or Fn+F3 to change my volume, after closer inspection I realized that the option to change my volume is somewhat corrupted.

[image: corrupted]

I then went to the sound settings, and the menu is completely broken.

[image: completely broken]

Last time I did something, I installed PulseAudio, but I just tried reinstalling it and its still not working.

Update 1: Booted from the Unity Control Center and the problem still persists there, so its probably not an issue with gnome.

Comment: This is related too: [Sound stopped working after crash Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320958/sound-stopped-working-after-crash-ubuntu-20-04)