# No sound on Kubuntu 20.10 / Dummy Output, No audio devices showing

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been having this reoccurring issue where the sound doesn't work on Kubuntu. It shows on the Sound icon a slash through it and it says there's "Dummy Output" with none of my sound devices showing.

When I connect my Bluetooth headphones it does have sound through those, just not anything else.

How do i fix this?

EDIT: To fix this what I did was kill PulseAudio & just restart it with these commands. Works perfectly now.

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To fix this what I did was kill PulseAudio & just restart it with these commands. Works perfectly now.

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```