# Random problems with audio on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, sound, microphone, headphones, zoom-meeting

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and I'm having problems with the audio, and I can;t understand the causes (it seems a bit random):

1. Sometimes I can't hear anything when connecting to Zoom. It happens even if I just restarted the notebook. So I need to restart the computer again until it works.
2. The microphone is constantly changing its level. Each time I plug or unplug, the levels are changed. And even if I set one level for each "profile" they change again, with no reason (usually for a higher value).

Can you help me? Any kind of trick here? EVen if it is a command that has worked for you to successfully restart the audio and not having to re-join the Zoom meetings I already joined?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: A command that would restart the PulseAudio service without rebooting would be `pulseaudio -k`