# mic is not working since Ubuntu 20.10 was installed

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a USB mixer with a mic plugged (Xenyx Q802USB).

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 my mic is not working.

This is my input devices shown in pulseaudio
[image]

I also noticed that there is no capture controls for the USB Device in `alsamixer`. This is what appears for me:

[image]

I tried to change the `~/.config/pulse/` folder and reboot the system, it didn't work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: not really, but I noticed that my Mixer has no capture controls in alsamixer