# Ubuntu 20.04.2 - No Audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, alsa, audio-jack

I am not able to hear anything in Ubuntu 20.04. There is absolutely no audio. Not even with ext. speakers. I need to fix this, as I have an important trip. Reinstalling Ubuntu is not an option.

**For your references:**

Dummy Output, no speaker or mic detected at all which wasn't earlier

However, alsamixer is detecting and it seems I can even configure it.

‘’’alsa studio’’’

I have already tried reisntalling alsa. Alsa studio is detecting the speaker and other audio related peripherals, but there is *still* no audio.

Does anyone else have this issue too? Or is it just me? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reinstall Ubuntu and tick the proprietary driver checkbox. You could also try Ubuntu 18.04 or 21.04. You should install those alongside though, so you don’t lose data.

Comment: 21.04 is not out it is beta.