# Ubuntustudio lost sound

Tags: sound, dell, laptop, ubuntu-studio, jack

I have UbuntuStudio dual boot with Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 5490 laptop. Audio worked fine for some months, but suddenly all I get in my session (my user) is a dummy audio output. Other user still uses the normal audio hardware.

Jack does not work any longer, so I can't open existing Ardour projects.

I am not able to tell exactly when sound stopped working. I recall Microsoft Teams did not detect microphone and sound output one day last week. Since then, I have no sound in my user, and limited sound (no jack) in other users in the same laptop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)