# Razer BlackShark V2 headset does not get sound, but is unmuted in alsamixer and pavucontrol

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headset, pavucontrol

I have sound coming from my integrated speakers, but not in my headset.

I've already tried alsamixer and pavucontrol and it's not working. I have a error message when I type `pulseaudio` in my terminal which goes like this:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Échec de pa_pid_file_create().
```

I've serched a post on this but non of solution worked and it actually broke my brighness settings (still not fixed).

It can be the driver of my headset wich is a Razer BlackShark V2, but I couldn't find it on Razer's website.
I'm a bit out of ideas ...

My computer is an Asus Strix laptop (UEFI) and I have a dual boot with Win 10/Ubuntu on GRUB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Comment: no it didn't ... I tried every solutions in here even if I had already made some.

Comment: I realy think that it is a driver problem now... when i plug the headset ubuntu recognize it as it change the audio for "headphone" instead of speaker when i plug it in. The problem is I couldn't find any driver for this headset online ... Do you have an idea where i can find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok for those who come in here in search of an answer: for now, in july 2021 there is no answer... The problem come from razer. Only the Kreken headset is supported on linux. So if you have a blackshark V2 like me or others Razer headset you just can't use it.
:'(